# calling REST service on form submit

Tags: html, rest, backbone.js

I am trying to call service `http://localhost:8080/app/search` It gets data in RequestBody as

```
{
  "skills":["c","java"],
  "country":["India"],
  "state":["Maharashtra","Gujrat"],
  "city":["Mumbai","Pune"],
  "highestDegree":["MCA","BE"],
   "functionalArea":["IT"],
  "functionalRole":["Tester"]
}
```

and header Content-Type:application/json
I tested above service with Postman and it gives me correct output. Now i tried to call above service from html form its giving me error that request is syntactically incorect.

My HTML form is

```
<form method="POST" action="http://localhost:8080/app/search">

<!--(form ellements with multiple select textbox )-->
</form
```

Is it right way or I need model from backbone?

Comment: try to use relative URL instead of writing complete URL

Comment: Or better you can try Ajax to call the rest service

Answer (score 0):

It's a wrong way, you have to create a Model and set it's url to your service :

```
var MyModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    url: '/app/search'
});
```

and when you click the submit button catch it in your view, set the form data in your model and call it's `save` function.